# Is extending a typescript namespace not allowed if defined with `export as namespace`?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

Working on a project that requires me to declare a new module of an existing Javascript library, however in creating the typings I noticed that when attempting to extend the namespace as it dictates in the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces), it completely overrides the pre-defined namespace.

I'm not sure if this is an illegal operation in typescript or an issue with how VSCode interprets the typings.

Example:

```
// file: existing.d.ts
export as namespace A;
export class Foo {}

// file: extensions.d.ts
namespace A {
    export class Bar {}
}

// resulting intellisense output
A.Foo // doesn't exist
A.Bar // exists
```

However if the original declaration of the namespace is changed to be in the format of `namespace A {}` it then works as expected.

Example:

```
// file: existing.d.ts
namespace A {
    export class Foo {}
}

// file: extensions.d.ts
namespace A {
    export class Bar {}
}

// resulting intellisense output
A.Foo // exists
A.Bar // exists
```

I guess the main question is if this is even legal in Typescript, or if this is an issue with VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `existing.d.ts` is a [UMD module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#umd-modules), i.e., an external module that also exposes itself as a UMD global `A`.  It's not possible to augment the UMD global directly.  Instead, you should augment the underlying external module by writing `declare module "module-name" { ... }` inside either (1) a file that contains top-level ES6 imports or exports and thus is an external module or (2) a dummy `declare module "dummy" { }` block in a file that is not an external module.  Augmentations made that way will be visible via the UMD global.

If you need more help getting this to work, please add more information to the question about the original library (e.g., its module name) and what extension you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is at how you declared the `namespace A` in your `existing.d.ts`
.

With your first example, you essentially say "I have `namespace A` and I have `class Foo`declared in my `existing.d.ts`"

With the second example, you essentially say "I have `namespace A` and I have `class Foo` that belongs to `namespace A` in my `existing.d.ts`"

`export as namespace A;` only declare the namespace.